# Div with horizontal scrolling only not working

Tags: html, scroll

I have a div with the following style:

```
height:200px;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
width:682px;
```

I need the elements to be next to each other on one line, with a horizontal scroll only.
The elements inside have the following styles:

```
width:60px;
padding:10px;
float:left;
```

But when they reach the end of the parent div, they start on a new row, while the horizontal scroll stays blank. Any ideas what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

P.S All elements are div-s.

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For reference see: http://jsfiddle.net/pz9AP/

Note, the wrapper div that is responsible for the actual scrolling. The contained items will float within the container element which in turn will scroll inside the wrapper.

```
#wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 682px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden; 
}

#container{
    width:2000px;  
}

.item{
    width:60px;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
}

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfect, thank you, but I cannot understand why when you say that the container is 2000px it does not take all the 2000px and ends at the last element? Is there a reasonable explanation or it's just magic?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the whitespace being removed. Would need to double check on that howerver.

Comment: Is there any workaround for Firefox, because there the 2000px are displayed and there's a lot of whitespace?

Comment: Interesting, Firefox is simply rendering the white space (as it should) where as chrome seems to remove it. With a bit of jquery you can dynamically get the width of the container items and set it: http://jsfiddle.net/pz9AP/2/