# Horizontal Scrollbar not showing

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #F2F1EF;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
#container {
    height:40px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.column {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:300px;
}
.post {
    height:40px;
}
```

And HTML as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
            <h1>Heading 2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
            <h1>Heading 4</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
            <h1>Heading 5</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="post">
            <h1>Heading 6</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to show horizontal scrollbar if the container has more columns in it but It hides the overflow content. My body has only this div#container for now.

Comment: Works for me (Safari 6.1, FF and Chrome latest). Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/n8hnv/

Comment: Why should the scrollbar show? The divs are inline-block elements and drop down vertically.

Comment: Using Mozilla, does not work :/

Comment: @j08691 I saw a post on SO that remove `float` and add `display:inline-block` and it will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893417/div-with-horizontal-scrolling-only-not-working/7894019#7894019

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.column` elements are still stacking vertically, but are just out of sight because of the static height of `#container` and its `overflow-y:hidden`. This is why a horizontal scroll bar will only appear when you scale the browser down to the width of a single `.column`.

To remedy this, well, you were on the right track. You need to use `white-space:nowrap` so that the `.column` elements will remain on the same line, and won't stack vertically. You need to apply it to the parent of the `.column` elements though, not to themselves:

```
#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Add this style to your definitions, and I think it will get you what you want. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

EDIT: Just in case you wanted to see what this achieves, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac2SP/).

Comment: I don't have any other accounts with StackExchange...feel free to send me a private message if you can't post a question, though.